# How to add constraints of derivative type to PDE using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

The PDE looks like

```
      x1_dot+h1_dot=J11*(x1+h1)+J12*(x2+h2)
      x2_dot+h2_dot=J21*(x1+h1)+J22*(x2+h2)
      s.t. Gradient(h1[x1_0,x2_0])=0 and Gradient(h2[x1_0,x2_0])=0 at fixed point of [x1_0,x2_0]
```

where `J11`, `J12`, `J21`, `J22` are coefficients; `h1` and `h2` are functions of `x1` and `x2`; `x1_dot` and `x2_dot` are the derivatives with respect to time `t`. `h1_dot` can be converted to partial_h1/dx1*x1_dot + partial_h1/dx2*x2_dot.

The ODE of d[x1,x2]/dt is as follows:

```
        x1_dot = w0*x2
        x2_dot = (Pm-Pe*Sin[x1]-Damp*x2)/TJ
```

So the fixed point can be computed as `x1_0=asin(Pm/Pe)=0.822, x2_0=0`

I have two questions.

1. How to add the constraints of Gradient(h1)=0 and Gradient(h2)=0.
2. I'm aware that I need more boundary conditions to make h1 and h2 unique, but above is everything I have. How can I give or estimate the right boundary conditions?

Below are my code and output from Mathematica

```
w0 = 314.1593
Pm = 1.2
Pe = 1.6382
Damp = 5
TJ = 6

NDSolve[{
   w0*x2 + D[h1[x1, x2], x1]*(w0*x2) + D[h1[x1, x2], x2]*(Pm - Pe*Sin[x1]
     - Damp*x2)/TJ == w0*(x2 + h2[x1, x2]), 
  (Pm - Pe*Sin[x1] - Damp*x2)/TJ + D[h2[x1, x2], x1]*(w0*x2) + 
    D[h2[x1, x2], x2]*(Pm - Pe*Sin[x1] - Damp*x2)/TJ ==
      -(Pe^2 - Pm^2)^0.5/TJ*(x1 + h1[x1, x2]) - 
        Damp/TJ*(x2 + h2[x1, x2])}, 
  {h1[x1, x2], h2[x1, x2]}, {x1, -1, 4}, {x2, -0.04, 0.04}
]

Plot3D[h1[x1, x2], {x1, -1, 4}, {x2, -0.04, 0.04}]
```

[image: empty plot]

Comment: I think using `NDSolveValue` should solve your problem

Comment: Is fixed point `{x10,x20}` inside region or on the border?

Comment: Note that h1 has no value associated to it by NDSolve; you obtain replacement rules, but a value is not assigned to h1, so in `Plot3D[h1[x1, x2], {x1, -1, 4}, {x2, -0.04, 0.04}]` you are plotting an unassigned function. You need to assigne the results of NDSolve to something (e.g. say, `solutionfromNDSolve`) then use something like: `Plot3D[h1[x1, x2] /. solutionFromNDSolve, {x1, -1, 4}, {x2, -0.04, 0.04}]`.

Comment: `Gradient` is an option for `FindMinimum[]`. Do you mean `Grad[h1[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]==0` and `Grad[h2[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]==0`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev The fixed point is inside the region. I was using  (D[h1[x1, x2], x1] ./{x1->x1_0, x2->x2_0})==0 in the NeumannValue condition, but the program threw an error. I didn't realize that Grad was an option for my case. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @mattiav27 Could you show me more details please? I'm really new to Mathematica.

Comment: @LeZHENG See my answer and let us discuss there.

Answer (score 2):

The direct problem to determine points `{x1,x2}` where restrictions $\nabla h1=\nabla h2=0$ are true has solution as follows:

```
w0 = 314.1593;
Pm = 1.2;
Pe = 1.6382;
Damp = 5;
TJ = 6;
eq = {w0*x2 + D[h1[x1, x2], x1]*(w0*x2) + 
     D[h1[x1, x2], x2]*(Pm - Pe*Sin[x1] - Damp*x2)/TJ == 
    w0*(x2 + h2[x1, x2]), (Pm - Pe*Sin[x1] - Damp*x2)/TJ + 
     D[h2[x1, x2], x1]*(w0*x2) + 
     D[h2[x1, x2], x2]*(Pm - Pe*Sin[x1] - Damp*x2)/
       TJ == -(Pe^2 - Pm^2)^0.5/TJ*(x1 + h1[x1, x2]) - 
     Damp/TJ*(x2 + h2[x1, x2])};
bc = DirichletCondition[{h1[x1, x2] == 0, h2[x1, x2] == 0}, x1 == -1];

s = NDSolve[{eq, bc}, {h1[x1, x2], h2[x1, x2]}, {x1, -1, 
    4}, {x2, -0.04, 0.04}];
```

Visualization of numerical solution

```
{Plot3D[h1[x1, x2] /. s[[1]], {x1, -1, 4}, {x2, -0.04, 0.04}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
 Plot3D[h2[x1, x2] /. s[[1]], {x1, -1, 4}, {x2, -0.04, 0.04}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Now we are looking points where restrictions are true, for this we use

```
eq1 = 
 eq /. {D[h1[x1, x2], x1] -> 0, D[h2[x1, x2], x2] -> 0, 
   D[h1[x1, x2], x2] -> 0, D[h2[x1, x2], x1] -> 0}

Out[]= {0. + 314.159 x2 == 314.159 (x2 + h2[x1, x2]), 
 0. + 1/6 (1.2 - 5 x2 - 1.6382 Sin[x1]) == -0.185869 (x1 + 
      h1[x1, x2]) - 5/6 (x2 + h2[x1, x2])}
```

Then we solve `eq1` using

```
Solve[eq1, {h1[x1, x2], h2[x1, x2]}]

Out[]= {{h1[x1, x2] -> -1.07603 - 1. x1 - 5.97316*10^-16 x2 + 
    1.46896 Sin[x1], h2[x1, x2] -> 0.}}
```

This general solution can be plot with our numerical solution as

```
Show[ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[h2[x1, x2] == 0. /. s], {x1, -1, 4}, {x2, -0.04, 0.04}], 
 ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[h1[x1, x2] == -1.076027972872623` - 1.` x1 - 
      5.973155153119597`*^-16 x2 + 1.4689575209666093` Sin[x1] /. 
    s], {x1, -1, 4}, {x2, -0.04, 0.04}, ContourStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Points where gray and red lines crossing we can calculate with

```
FindRoot[{Evaluate[h2[x1, x2] == 0. /. s], 
  h1[x1, x2] == -1.076027972872623` - 1.` x1 - 
     5.973155153119597`*^-16 x2 + 1.4689575209666093` Sin[x1] /. 
   s}, {{x1, 2.5}, {x2, 0}}]

Out[]= {x1 -> 2.32257, x2 -> -0.000184708}

 FindRoot[{Evaluate[h2[x1, x2] == 0. /. s], 
  h1[x1, x2] == -1.076027972872623` - 1.` x1 - 
     5.973155153119597`*^-16 x2 + 1.4689575209666093` Sin[x1] /. 
   s}, {{x1, .8}, {x2, 0}}]

Out[]= {x1 -> 0.820887, x2 -> -7.45875*10^-7}
```

Therefore in this case of special type of boundary condition we got  two point. Now let consider invers problem: for a given points we need to define boundary conditions. Obviously this problem has no unique solution. But it can be solved with this code:

```
w0 = 314.1593;
Pm = 1.2;
Pe = 1.6382;
Damp = 5;
TJ = 6;
eq = {w0*x2 + D[h1[x1, x2], x1]*(w0*x2) + 
     D[h1[x1, x2], x2]*(Pm - Pe*Sin[x1] - Damp*x2)/TJ == 
    w0*(x2 + h2[x1, x2]), (Pm - Pe*Sin[x1] - Damp*x2)/TJ + 
     D[h2[x1, x2], x1]*(w0*x2) + 
     D[h2[x1, x2], x2]*(Pm - Pe*Sin[x1] - Damp*x2)/
       TJ == -(Pe^2 - Pm^2)^0.5/TJ*(x1 + h1[x1, x2]) - 
     Damp/TJ*(x2 + h2[x1, x2])};
bc = DirichletCondition[{h1[x1, x2] == a1, h2[x1, x2] == a2}, 
   x1 == -1];
 eq1 = eq /. {D[h1[x1, x2], x1] -> 0, D[h2[x1, x2], x2] -> 0, 
   D[h1[x1, x2], x2] -> 0, D[h2[x1, x2], x1] -> 0};
sol1=Solve[eq1, {h1[x1, x2], h2[x1, x2]}];   
x10 = 0.822; x20 = 0; c = 
 Last[First[First[sol1]]] /. {x1 -> x10, x2 -> x20}
sol0 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, bc}, {h1[x10, x20], 
   h2[x10, x20]}, {x1, -1, 4}, {x2, -0.04, 0.04}, {b1, b2}];
s = FindRoot[{sol0[a1, a2][[2]] == 0, 
   sol[a1, a2][[1]] == c}, {{a1, 0.}, {a2, 0.}}]
(*{a1 -> -0.822004, a2 -> 0.}*)
```

Using parameters `a1,a2` we can evaluate and plot solution

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, bc}, {h1, h2}, {x1, -1, 
   4}, {x2, -0.04, 0.04}, {a1, a2}]


{Plot3D[sol[-.822004, 0][[1]][x1, x2], {x1, -1, 4}, {x2, -0.04, 0.04}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
 Plot3D[sol[-.822004, 0][[2]][x1, x2], {x1, -1, 4}, {x2, -0.04, 0.04}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

It is not unique solution, since we can apply some boundary condition for any border as well.

Comment: Thanks Alex. It's really interesting that you compute the fixed points. x1_0=0.822 and x2_0=0 should be a priori conditions. And you just compute them from nowhere.

Comment: Sorry I should make myself more clear and provide all the conditions. I want to estimate function h1[x1,x2] and h2[x1,x2], given the PDEs and condition ∇h1[0.822,0]=∇h2[0.822,0]=0.

Comment: ∇h1 and ∇h2 are zeros at specific points, not all the regions. So `eq1 = 
 eq /. {D[h1[x1, x2], x1] -> 0, D[h2[x1, x2], x2] -> 0, 
   D[h1[x1, x2], x2] -> 0, D[h2[x1, x2], x1] -> 0}` is not true.

Comment: You are not right with the last decision since `eq1=0` is true in specific points only. Now check that second point I have calculated,  `{x1 -> 0.820887, x2 -> -7.45875*10^-7}`, is very closed to that you are looking for, `x10=0.822; x20=0`. Therefore, homogeneous Dirichlet  condition `bc` I have used practically are solve you problem.

Comment: @LeZHENG See update to my answer with some solution of inverse problem.

Comment: Thanks Alex. x10=0.822; x20=0 is not what I'm looking for, but a given condition since I can compute the fixed points easily for my system. I've edited my questions to make it more precise.

Comment: The problem with 1 point has no unique solution. Also I don't understand manipulation with derivative respect to time. In the beginning you have 4 ODEs and 2 constrains. This problem could be better to optimise with respect to initial data $x1(0)=x10, x2(0)=x20$. Then we have a chance to get unique solution.

Comment: Hi Alex, that's because I'm more interested in what h1 and h2 look like in the span of x1 and x2, instead of how h1 and h2 evolve over time.

Comment: @LeZHENG But you don't know how  h1 and h2 look like in the span of x1 and x2 since you don't know boundary conditions. Could you give me parameters `J11,J12,J21,J22` for the initial system?

Comment: Alex, J=[J11, J12; J21, J22] is the Jacobian matrix at the fixed point [x10, x20]. ```J11=0, J12=w0, J21= -(Pe^2-Pm^2)^0.5/TJ, J22= -Damp/TJ```. They are already in the Mathematica code eq={...}. As for the boundary conditions, that's really an issue for my problem. BTW, the more abstract problem is that I have a nonlinear dynamical system ```xdot=f(x)```. I'd like to find the diffeomorphism of the system ```y=x+h(x)``` to make ```ydot=J*y``` and ```gradient(y0)=Identity matrix```, which equals ```gradient(h(x0))=0```.

Comment: @LeZHENG Do you mean the Banach theorem about fixed point?

Comment: Hi Alex, it's more like an extension of the Hartman-Grobman theorem, given in “LinearizationinthelargeofnonlinearsystemsandKoopmanoperatorspectrum” Theorem 2.3

Comment: @LeZHENG Then `h(x1,x2)` can be not unique, but only bounded and second algorithm is applicable.

Comment: Hi Alex, yes, I get more or less what I expected from the inverse problem you posted. Thanks for all the explanation. Just one last question, where does this condition come from `bc = DirichletCondition[{h1[x1, x2] == a1, h2[x1, x2] == a2}, x1 == -1];` and can I change it to others, like `x1=-2`?

Comment: @LeZHENG Yes, we can define region with any border, and obviously we can expand the given one.

Comment: Hi Alex, in the reverse problem you gave, what's the purpose of defining eq1, sol1, and c? I'm reviewing the problem and want to know more about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LeZHENG Actually it is not reverse problem, it is inverse problem (for a given points `x10, x20` we need to define boundary conditions). This is the problem you asking about in your post. To solve this problem we need to define `eq1, sol1` and `c`.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you very much for the quick reply. I think I understand your logic, but I fail to follow your process. Would you mind communicating via emails or skype? It's not efficient since we have a time difference. My email address is zhengl20@ncepu.edu.cn.

Comment: @LeZHENG Ok! Let us communicate by email. Also you can start new post with all questions about my code.

Comment: Alex, I've replied to your email. My main question is that your code doesn't work well for another system, which I know the analytical solution of h1 and h2. That's in the post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238346/how-can-i-solve-a-system-of-pdes-with-constraints-but-having-unknown-boundary-co , with the new simpler example ODE.