# How can I solve a system of PDEs with constraints but having unknown boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, boundary-conditions

I have a 1st order system of two PDEs with two independent variables and two dependent variables.

```
mu = -0.1;
lambda = -1;
x10 = 0;
x20 = 0;
eq = 
  {mu*x1 + D[h1[x1, x2], x1]*mu*x1 + D[h1[x1, x2], x2]*lambda*(x2 - x1^2) == 
     mu*(x1 + h1[x1, x2]), 
   lambda*(x2 - x1^2) + D[h2[x1, x2], x1]*mu*x1 + D[h2[x1, x2], x2]*lambda*(x2 - x1^2) == 
     lambda*(x2 + h2[x1, x2])};
```

The domain is given by `{x1, -2, 2}` and `{x2, -2, 2}`. The problem is that I don't know the boundary condition of the PDE, but I do have a constraint that the gradient of `h1` and `h2` at point `{x10, x20}` is zero.

```
D[h1[x1, x2], x1]/.{x1 -> x10, x2 -> x20} == 0
D[h1[x1, x2], x2]/.{x1 -> x10, x2 -> x20} == 0
D[h2[x1, x2], x1]/.{x1 -> x10, x2 -> x20} == 0
D[h2[x1, x2], x2]/.{x1 -> x10, x2 -> x20} == 0
```

How can I compute an approximation to `h1[x1, x2]` and `h2[x1, x2]` numerically?

Comment: That is not enough information. For a numerical integration you need a definite region. And you need initial and boundary conditions. Derivatives at only one point are not enough.

Comment: @DanielHuber  The region is {x1, -2, 2} and {x2, -2, 2}. But the initial and boundary conditions are unknown.

Comment: Then there is no unique solution.

Comment: @DanielHuber Yes, I know there is no unique solution. How can I get any feasible solution?

Comment: This needs work. First this is not a system of coupled PDE, you can solve it separately. Further, look at your equations for x1==x2==0. The equation for h1 then reads: `0. == -0.1 h1[0, 0]` what does not define the derivatives. Likewise for h2.

Comment: @LeZHENG You can use code from my answer on  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234909/how-to-add-constraints-of-derivative-type-to-pde-using-ndsolve/234963?noredirect=1#comment601894_234963

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the relevant mathematics.

Comment: @m_goldberg  I'm not so sure that the question is unsuitable here.

Answer (score 5):

The two PDE are independent, and solutions to the second can be obtained without difficulty.  First, for convenience, move all terms to the left side of the equation and also rationalize `mu`.

```
Subtract @@ eq[[2]]
(* x1^2 + h2[x1, x2] - (-x1^2 + x2)*D[h2[x1, x2],x2] - (x1*D[h2[x1, x2],x1])/10 *)
```

`x2` appears explicitly only as the coefficient of `D[h2[x1, x2],x2]`, so let us suppose that `h2` is a function of `x1` only.  (This may exclude some solutions, but the OP asked for any solution.)

```
% /. h2 -> Function[{x1, x2}, h2[x1]]
(* x1^2 + h2[x1] - 1/10 x1 h2'[x1] *)

DSolveValue[% == 0, h2[x1], x1]
(* -((5 x1^2)/4) + x1^10 C[1] *)
```

It also satisfies `D[h2[x1, x2], x1]/.{x1 -> x10, x2 -> x20} == 0`,as desired.

A similar calculation can be performed for the first equation.

```
Subtract @@ eq[[1]];
% /. h1 -> Function[{x1, x2}, h1[x1]];
DSolveValue[% == 0, h1[x1], x1]
(* x1 C[1] *)
```

However, the requirement that `D[h1[x1, x2], x1]/.{x1 -> x10, x2 -> x20} == 0` requires that `C[1] = 0`, yielding only the trivial solution.

**Addendum**

Further investigation shows that `DSolve` can  provide general solutions for the two PDEs.

```
s1 = DSolveValue[eq[[1]], h1[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]
(* x1 C[1][-(5/(4 x1^8)) + x2/x1^10] *)

s2 = DSolveValue[eq[[2]], h2[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]
(* -((5 x1^2)/4) + x1^10 C[1][-(5/(4 x1^8)) + x2/x1^10] *)
```

where `C[1]` is an arbitrary function of `z = (x2 - 5 x1^2/4)/x1^10`. (In fact, `DSolve` cans solve many quasilinear PDEs.)  To apply the constraints at `{x10, x20}`, `C[1]` must be well behaved there, as it is for the specific solutions derived earlier in this answer (for which `C[1]` is constant).  Possibly, other specific solutions satisfying the constraints can be found among the many possible `C[1]` functions.  For instance Sinh[z]/Cosh[z]^3 is continuously differentiable at `(0, 0}` and satisfies the constraints, although it is not analytical there.  Whether such a solution is acceptable depends of how the OP plans to use it.

**Addendum 2**

The OP posed a similar but coupled pair of PDEs in a comment below:

```
eq1 = {-1/10*x1 - (-x1^2 + x2)*D[h1[x1, x2], x2] - x1*D[h1[x1, x2], x1]/10 ==
       (-x1 - h1[x1, x2])/10 - h2[x1, x2], 
       x1^2 - x2 - (-x1^2 + x2)*D[h2[x1, x2], x2] - x1*D[h2[x1, x2], x1]/10 == 
       -x2 - h2[x1, x2]}
```

`DSolve` can  solve these ODEs, but only with assistance.  Because `eq1[[2]]` is as before, its solution determined above can be inserted into `eq1[[1]]`.

```
eq1s = Simplify[Subtract @@ eq1[[1]] /. 
    h2 -> Function[{x1, x2}, x1^10 c1[(x2 - 5 x1^2/4)/x1^10] - 5 x1^2/4]]
(* (-5*x1^2)/4 + x1^10*c1[((-5*x1^2)/4 + x2)/x1^10] + h1[x1, x2]/10 + 
   x1^2*D[h1[x1, x2], x2] - x2*D[h1[x1, x2], x2] - x1*D[h1][x1, x2], x1]/10 *)
```

The inhomogeneous term `-((5 x1^2)/4)` contributes `-(25 x1^2)/2` to the solution for `h1`, as can be seen from evaluating

```
DSolve[-((5*x1^2)/4) + (1/10)*h1[x1, x2] - (1/10)*x1*D[h1[x1, x2], x1] == 0, 
    h1[x1, x2], x1]
```

On this basis perform the second substitution,

```
Simplify[eq1s /. 
    h1 -> Function[{x1, x2}, h1[x1] c c1[(x2 - 5 x1^2/4)/x1^10] - 25 x1^2/2]]
(* 1/10 c1[(-((5 x1^2)/4) + x2)/x1^10] (10 x1^10 + c h1[x1] - c x1 D[h1[x1], x1]) *)
```

(`h1` and `h2` must involve the same function `c1`, up to a constant multiplier designated `c`, in order to solve the two equations.  The solution to this last ODE is

```
DSolveValue[% == 0, h1[x1], x1]
(* (10 x1^10)/(9 c) + x1 C[1] *)
```

Gathering the solutions together and back-substituting them into `eq1` verifies their validity.

```
Simplify[eq1 /. 
   {h1 -> Function[{x1, x2}, (10 x1^10/9 + c x1) c2[(x2 - 5 x1^2/4)/x1^10] - 25 x1^2/2],
    h2 -> Function[{x1, x2}, x1^10 c2[(x2 - 5 x1^2/4)/x1^10] - 5 x1^2/4]}]
(* {True, True} *)
```

For the case of `c2` constant and the constraints applied, the solution becomes

```
h1 -> Function[{x1, x2}, 10 x1^10/9 c2 - 25 x1^2/2]
h2 -> Function[{x1, x2}, x1^10 c2 - 5 x1^2/4]}]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In general, the two PDEs are not independent. Just this simple example decouples the two PDEs. The solution given in the Addendum is very interesting. Will it work if the two PDEs are dependent on each other? For example, the PDEs look like this: `eq = {mu*x1 + D[h1[x1, x2], x1]*mu*x1 + D[h1[x1, x2], x2]*lambda*(x2 - x1^2) == mu*(x1 + h1[x1, x2])+lambda*h2[x1,x2],   lambda*(x2 - x1^2) + D[h2[x1, x2], x1]*mu*x1 + D[h2[x1, x2], x2]*lambda*(x2 - x1^2) == lambda*(x2 + h2[x1, x2])};`

Comment: @LaZheng  In general, coupling the two PDEs makes them much  more difficult to solve.  For the equations in your comment, however, it should not be difficult.  I shall do so later today.

Comment: @LeZHENG  As you requested I have added the general solution to the coupled equations in your comment.  This was relatively easy, because the two PDEs still had the same Characteristic surfaces even after coupling.  Note that the general solution is not analytic at `{0, 0}`, which may be a consideration in choosing which solutions to use.  The exception of course is to take `c2` as a constant.  By the way, I voted to reopen your question, but that probably won't happen.  Too bad.

Comment: @LeZHENG  I hope you will become a regular contributor to Mathematica.SE.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.  Best wishes.

Comment: Never mind, maybe it's really bad question and your answer is a new year gift for me. It's the first time that I see what DSolveValue can do. And I got another PDE to solve, the format is like the above, but maybe because it's complicated that DSolveValue gives no answer. I post the codes in the comment below.

Comment: `w0 = 314.15;
Pm = 1.2;
Pe = 1.64;
P1 = 1.12;
Damp = 5;
TJ = 6;
lambda1 = -0.42 + 7.63 I;
lambda2 = -0.42 - 7.63 I;
eq = {D[h1[x1, x2], x1]*(w0*x2) + D[h1[x1, x2], x2]*(Pm - Pe*Sin[x1] - Damp*x2)/TJ == lambda1*h1[x1, x2],  D[h2[x1, x2], x1]*(w0*x2) + D[h2[x1, x2], x2]*(Pm - Pe*Sin[x1] - Damp*x2)/TJ == lambda2*h2[x1, x2]};
s1 = DSolveValue[eq[[1]], h1[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]
s2 = DSolveValue[eq[[2]], h2[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]`

Comment: @LeZHENG  Probably, DSolve produced an implicit equation during the solution process and was unable to invert it.  At one time it was possible sometimes to circumvent the problem by changing options for `Solve`, which is called by `DSolve` in such circumstances.  Now, doing so is much more difficult.  I recommend that you ask a new question featuring one of the two new equations, which appear to be the same.

Comment: @LeZHENG  Reading a few article on the Method of Characteristics also might be useful.  For instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics.

Comment: After simplifying my PDEs, I think I can make my PDEs decoupled and each of them looks like `D[h[x1, x2], x1]*f(x1, x2)+D[h[x1, x2], x2]*g(x1, x2)=lambda*h[x1,x2], s.t. gradient(h(x10,x20))=0`, where f and g are functions of x1 and x2. This looks much simpler. But still I'm afraid that only a few f and g can give me analytical solution of h. From your opinion, what new question should I raise?

Comment: @LeZHENG  Ask for help on a specific ODE that is important to you, not a generic one.  Provide the code you tried and described the problems you encountered.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I've posted a new one. I think I've made myself clear in the new post. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238547/numerically-solve-pdes-with-constraints-and-without-boundary-solution

Comment: @LeZHENG  Almost certainly, you will be asked, "What have you tried?"  I recommend that you provide that information in your question now, before you are asked.  For instance, you could try `DSolve[D[h[x1, x2], x1]*f[x1, x2] + D[h[x1, x2], x2]*g[x1, x2] == h[x1, x2], h[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]`.  If that is what you choose to do, be sure to mention the how Mathematica responded.  By the way, I corrected a typo in your first equation, replacing `=` by `==`.

Comment: Oh, you are so kind. I've edited my post under your instructions. Thank you very much!!!!