# Numerically solve PDEs with constraints and without boundary solution

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-conditions

I have a PDE like

```
D[h[x1, x2], x1]*a[x1,x2]+D[h[x1,x2], x2]*b[x1,x2] + c[x1,x2] == h[x1,x2]
s.t. gradient(h(0,0))==0
```

where a,b,c are known functions of x1 and x2, and h are the function to be solved. x1 and x2 are both in [-2, 2].
For some selected a,b,c, DSolveValue can give me perfect analytical solutions, like (a=0.1*x1, b=x2-x1^2, c=-x1^2)

```
eq1 = -x1^2 + D[h1[x1, x2], x1]*(0.1)*x1 + 
    D[h1[x1, x2], x2]*(x2 - x1^2) == h1[x1, x2];
s1 = DSolveValue[eq1, h1[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]
(*x1^2. (-1.25 + x1^8. C[1][(0.25 (-5. x1^2 + 4. x2))/x1^10])*)
```

For this analytical solution, I then use the gradient constraints to figure out how C[1] should look like and finally get h1=-1.25*x1^2, which is the solution I want.
But for other a,b,c, DSolveValue reports that "Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so solutions may not be found". For example (a=x2, b=Sin[x1]+x2, c=0):

```
eq2 = D[h2[x1, x2], x1]*x2 + D[h2[x1, x2], x2]*(Sin[x1] + x2) == 
   h2[x1, x2];
s2 = DSolveValue[eq2, h2[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]
```

The output just repeats my cmd and doesn't have a solution.
I'm aware that this is because h2 doesn't have an analytical solution. How to get a numerical solution under this circumstance?

Comment: First we need to restrict `x1, x2` as well.

Comment: Your PDE does not define the derivatives at x1==x2==0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Linear PDEs typically are solved by the method of characteristics.  For the PDE in the question, the ODEs of the characteristics are

```
{x2'[s] == Sin[x1[s]] + x2[s], x1'[s] == x2[s], h'[s] == h[s]}
```

Attempting to solve these ODEs with `DSolve` is unsuccessful, returning the `Solve::ifun` error message.  That this is the same error cited in the question is not surprising, because `DSolve` itself undoubtedly uses the method of characteristics when attempting to solve a linear or quasilinear PDE.  (See questions [238346](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238375/1063) and [238808](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238863/1063) for examples in which the characteristics, and therefore the PDE, can be solved symbolically.)  However, `NDSolve` can  evaluate the characteristics with little difficulty.  Focus first on the ODEs for `(x1, x2}`.

```
sp = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x2'[s] == Sin[x1[s]] + x2[s], x1'[s] == x2[s], 
    x1[0] == x10, x2[0] == x20}, {x1[s], x2[s]}, {s, -10, 10}, {x10, x20}];
Table[sp[n, -2], {n, -4.03, 2, .1}];
pt = ParametricPlot[%, {s, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {x1, x2}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, 
    PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798]];
```

Before displaying the result, let us superimpose (in black) the two stream lines that pass through the origin.

```
NDSolveValue[{x2'[s] == Sin[x1[s]] + x2[s], x1'[s] == x2[s], x1[10^-5] == 10^-5, 
    x2[10^-5] == 10^-5 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5])}, {x1[s], x2[s]}, {s, -50, 50}];
pt0 = ParametricPlot[%, {s, -50, 50}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}];
Show[pt, pt /. Line[z_] -> Line[-z], pt0, pt0 /. Line[z_] -> Line[-z]]
```

[image]

(The substitution, `Line[z_] -> Line[-z]` reflects the solution in the origin, reducing computations by a factor of two.)  Now, the point of evaluating the characteristics is that `h2[x1, x2]` satisfies

```
DSolveValue[h'[s] == h[s], h[s], s]
(* E^s C[1] *)
```

along each stream line, with `C[1]` a constant that can vary from stream line to stream line.  Consequently, if the value of `h2[x1, x2]` is known anywhere on each stream line, its value is known everywhere.  The question above specifies only that the gradient of `h2[x1, x2]` vanishes at the origin.  From the PDE, it immediately follows that `h2[0, 0]` also vanishes, and the value of `h2[x1, x2]` must be zero everywhere along the  black lines.  Moreover, `h[x1, x2]` also must vanish on characteristics passing infinitesimally close to the origin.  However, values of `h2[x1, x2]` on other stream lines are unspecified.

For completeness, here is a plot of the stream lines over a larger domain.

```
rl = Table[{Line[z_] :> Line[{2 nn Pi + #[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ z]} /. 
    nn -> n, {n, -2, 2}];
Table[sp[n, -4], {n, -6 Pi, 3 Pi, Pi/5}];
ParametricPlot[%, {s, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-4, 4}}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {x1, x2}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, 
    PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798]];
Show[%, % /. Line[z_] -> Line[-z], Replace[{pt0, pt0 /. Line[z_] -> Line[-z]},
    rl, All]]
```

[image]

As would be expected, the structure of the stream lines is periodic in `x1` with period `2 Pi`.  Finally, it should be noted that `StreamPlot` can produce similar plots, although with less detail.

**Response to OP's comment**

[Le ZHENG](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/75790/le-zheng) asked in a comment below about the initial conditions in

```
    NDSolveValue[{x2'[s] == Sin[x1[s]] + x2[s], x1'[s] == x2[s], x1[10^-5] == 10^-5, 
    x2[10^-5] == 10^-5 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5])}, {x1[s], x2[s]}, {s, -50, 50}];
```

used above.  They were obtained by combining the first two characteristic equations at the beginning of the answer to obtain

```
x2'[x1] == (Sin[x1] + x2[x1])/x2[x1]
```

For stream lines passing through the origin, `x2'[x1]` is equal to `x2[x1]/x1`.  With these expressions set to `a` for convenience, the preceding equation becomes `a == 1/a + 1`, which has the solutions

```
Solve[a == 1/a + 1, a] // Flatten
(* {a -> 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5]), a -> 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])} *)
```

Hence, very near the origin `x2 = x1 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5])` for one stream line and `x2 = x1 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])` for the other.  I chose "very near" to be `x1 = 10^-5`.  And, because the set of characteristic equations is autonomous (not explicitly dependent on `s`), I could choose `s` corresponding to `x1 = 10^-5` to be any value whatsoever.  I chose it equal to `x1`.

By the way, no stream lines pass through `{2 PI n, 0}`. with `n` an odd integer.  Instead, they spiral around those points with exponentially decreasing radii.

**Sample Complete Numerical Solution**

As a sample solution, choose `h[x1,x2] = (x1^2 +x2^2)/4` along the x and y axes, which is sufficient to completely determine `h` and satisfies the requirements that `h` and its gradients vanish at the origin.  It is convenient for this computation to eliminate `s` from the characteristic ODEs in favor of `x1` or `x2`.

```
sp1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x2'[x1] == (Sin[x1] + x2[x1])/x2[x1], 
    h'[x1] == h[x1]/x2[x1], x2[0] == x0, h[0] == x0^2/4, 
    WhenEvent[x2[x1] > 3.5, "StopIntegration"]}, {x1, x2[x1], h[x1]}, {x1, -2, 2}, x0];
sp2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x1'[x2] == x2/(Sin[x1[x2]] + x2), 
    h'[x2] == h[x2]/(Sin[x1[x2]] + x2), x1[0] == x0, h[0] == x0^2/4, 
    WhenEvent[x1[x2] > 2, "StopIntegration"]}, {x1[x2], x2, h[x2]}, {x2, -2, 2}, x0];

plt1 = Show@Table[tem = sp1[n]; ParametricPlot3D[tem, 
    Evaluate[Join[{x1}, Flatten[Last[tem] /. x1 -> "Domain"]]], 
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 1.5}}, AxesLabel -> {x1, x2, h}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}], {n, .01, 3.5, .05}];
plt2 = Show@Table[tem = sp2[n]; ParametricPlot3D[tem, 
    Evaluate[Join[{x2}, Flatten[Last[tem] /. x2 -> "Domain"]]], 
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 1.5}}, AxesLabel -> {x1, x2, h}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}], {n, .01, 2, .05}];
Show[plt1, plt1 /. Line[z_] :> Line[Map[{-#[[1]], -#[[2]], #[[3]]} &, z]], 
     plt2, plt2 /. Line[z_] :> Line[Map[{-#[[1]], -#[[2]], #[[3]]} &, z]]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

As expected, `h = 0` on the stream lines passing through the origin and those infinitesimally close.  The solution also can be displayed with `Plot3D`.

```
Flatten[Cases[%, Line[z_] -> z, Infinity], 1];
ListPlot3D[%, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 1.5}}, AxesLabel -> {x1, x2, h}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Comment: The answer is fantasy. Let me try to digest it. Thank you very much.

Comment: hi bbgodfrey, where does `x1[10^-5] == 10^-5, x2[10^-5] == 10^-5 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5])` come from in the code?

Comment: @LeZHENG  I have addressed you last comment at the end of my answer above.  By the way, I suggest that you 1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

It also is possible to obtain an approximate symbolic solution, valid for small `x1`.  Expand the PDE in `x1` to obtain

```
DSolve[(x1 + x2)*D[h[x1, x2] + x2*D[h[x1, x2] == h[x1, x2], h[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]
```

Although `DSolve` cannot solve this PDE directly, it can solve the characteristic ODEs.

```
{x2'[s] == x1[s] + x2[s], x1'[s] == x2[s], h'[s] == h[s]}
```

Focus first on the ODEs for {x1, x2}

```
DSolve[{x1'[s] == x2[s], x2'[s] == x1[s] + x2[s]}, {x1[s], x2[s]}, s] // Flatten
sol = ((Simplify[% /. C[n_] -> C[n] Exp[-s/2]] // ExpToTrig // Simplify) 
/. C[n_] -> C[n] Exp[s/2]) // Simplify
(* {x1[s] -> 1/5 E^(s/2) (5 C[1] Cosh[(Sqrt[5] s)/2] - 
             Sqrt[5] (C[1] - 2 C[2]) Sinh[(Sqrt[5] s)/2]), 
    x2[s] -> 1/5 E^(s/2) (5 C[2] Cosh[(Sqrt[5] s)/2] + 
             Sqrt[5] (2 C[1] + C[2]) Sinh[(Sqrt[5] s)/2])} *)
```

which can be plotted as

```
Show[ParametricPlot[Table[{x1[s], x2[s]} /. sol /. {C[1] -> n, C[2] -> 0}, 
    {n, -2,   2, .1}], {s, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}], 
ParametricPlot[Table[{x1[s], x2[s]} /. solt /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> n}, {n, -3, 3, .1}], 
    {s, -3, 3}]]
```

[image]

Compare this to the first plot in my strictly numerical answer above.  Clearly, they are about the same for small `x1`.  Next, obtain a symbolic solution for `h`.  Consider the quadratic expression, `(x1[s] + x2[s]/2)^2 - 5/4 x2[s]^2)`, which reduces to

```
Simplify[((x1[s] + x2[s]/2)^2 - 5/4 x2[s]^2) /. sol /. C[2] -> 0]
(* E^s C[1]^2 *)
```

and

```
DSolve[h'[s] == h[s], h[s], s] /. C[1] -> C[3]
(* {{h[s] -> E^s C[3]}} *)
```

`E^s` can be eliminated between these two results to yield

```
h[x1, x2] == Simplify[(x1 + x2/2)^2 - 5/4 x2^2] C[3]/C[1]^2
(* h[x1, x2] == ((x1^2 + x1 x2 - x2^2) C[3])/C[1]^2 *)
```

Similarly, assuming `C[2] -> 0` leads to

```
(* h[x1, x2] == ((-x1^2 - x1 x2 + x2^2) C[3])/C[2]^2 *)
```

Choose as boundary conditions `h[x1,x2] = (x1^2 +x2^2)/4` along the `x1` and `X2` axes, as done in the numerical solution above.  Then, `C[3]/C[2]^2` reduces to `1/4` on the `x1` axis, and `C[3]/C[1]^2` reduces to `1/4` on the `x2` axis.  Combining these expressions gives for `h`

```
h[x1, x2] = Abs[(x1^2 + x1 x2 - x2^2)/4];
```

which can be plotted as

```
Plot3D[Abs[(x1^2 + x1 x2 - x2^2)/4], {x1, -2, 2}, {x2, -2, 2}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, AxesLabel -> {x1, x2, h}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

which agrees well for small `x1` with the final plot in the numerical answer above.