# DSolve a partial differential equation with two boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, boundary-conditions

While trying to solve:
$$
z \frac{\partial}{\partial z} (z G(s,z))=z \cosh (s) \frac{\partial}{\partial z} G(s,z)-\frac{1}{2}
\sinh (s) \frac{\partial}{\partial s}  G(s,z)
$$
using DSolve it gives a family of solutions:

```
FullSimplify[
 DSolve[-z D[z G[s, z], 
     z] == - z Cosh[s] D[G[s, z], z] + (1/2) Sinh[s] D[G[s, z], s],
   G, {s, z}]]
(* {{G -> 
   Function[{s, 
     z}, -(((-2 Csch[s]^2 - 2 z Log[Tanh[s/2]] - 
        z Csch[s]^2 Log[Tanh[s/2]] + 
        z Cosh[2 s] Csch[s]^2 Log[Tanh[s/2]]) C[1][(
       Csch[s]^2 (2 - 2 z Cosh[s] + z Log[Tanh[s/2]] - 
          z Cosh[2 s] Log[Tanh[s/2]]))/(2 z)])/z)]}} *)
```

However I want a specific solution which satisfies:

$$
G(0,z)=\frac{1}{z-1} \;\; \mbox{and} \;\;\frac{\partial}{\partial s}G(s,z) \Big \vert_{s=0}=\frac{\sqrt{z}}{(z-1)^\frac{3}{2}} \;.
$$
I do not know how to implement the conditions. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As you see from the solution, the function is not defined for `s==0`because of the `Csch` term. Therefore you can not specify `G[0,z]`. The same pertains to the second condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us suppose that we are interested only in the solution for small `s`, which seems reasonable, because the question addresses applying boundary conditions at `s == 0`.    Then the PDE becomes

```
eq = -z D[z G[s, z], z] == -z D[G[s, z], z] + (1/2) s D[G[s, z], s]
```

and solving it with `DSolve` yields

```
G[s, z] -> C[1][Log[-((-1 + z)/(s^2 z))]]/(s^2 z)
```

i.e., an arbitrary function of `Log[-((-1 + z)/(s^2 z))]` divided by `s^2 z`.  The problem with this solution is that `DSolve` does not concern itself with such niceties as branch cuts.  If, in the same spirit, I do not worry about branch cuts either, then just a few minutes of thought suggests the solution

```
 sol = G -> Function[{s, z}, 1/(z - 1) + s Sqrt[z/(z - 1)^3]]
```

Clearly, it satisfies the the two conditions listed in the question.  And, it actually satisfies the PDE, as can be seen from

```
Simplify[eq/.sol]
(* True *)
```

Probably this solution is not unique, more general solutions being power series in `s Sqrt[z/(z - 1)]`.

Although I do not have time now to solve the actual PDE posed in the question, I can say with confidence that it does have a solution, and that solution reduces to the one here in the limit of small `s`.

**Addendum: Solution for original PDE**

The full PDE in the question,

```
eq1 = -z D[z G[s, z], z] == -z Cosh[s] D[G[s, z], z] + (1/2) Sinh[s] D[G[s, z], s]
```

has the solution

```
DSolve[eq1, G[s, z], {s, z}][[1, 1]]
(* G[s, z] -> (2 Csch[s]^2 C[1][(Csch[s]^2 (2 - 2 z Cosh[s] + 
   z Log[Tanh[s/2]] - z Cosh[2 s] Log[Tanh[s/2]]))/(2 z)])/z *)
```

obtained using Mathematica "12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)".  From this general solution, construct the specific solution

```
sol1 = G -> Function[{s, z}, 
    1/(z Cosh[s] - 1 + 1/2 z (Cosh[2 s] - 1) Log[Tanh[s/2]]) + 
    Sinh[s] Sqrt[z/(z Cosh[s] - 1 + z/2 (Cosh[2 s] - 1) Log[Tanh[s/2]])^3]];
```

It satisfies the two constraints,

```
Series[G[s, z] /. sol1, {s, 0, 0}] // Normal
(* 1/(-1 + z) *)

Series[D[G[s, z] /. sol1, s], {s, 0, 0}] // Normal
(* Sqrt[z/(-1 + z)^3] *)
```

and, of course, satisfies the PDE.

```
FullSimplify[eq1 /. sol1]
(* True *)
```

Note that the solution given is not necessarily the most general one, which would be a power series in `Sinh[s]` with the two lowest order terms given in `sol1`.  Note also that `sol1` may not be analytical at `s == 0`, but it is continuously differentiable there, which is sufficient for our purposes.  For completeness, the characteristic curves of the PDE can be illustrated by

```
StreamPlot[{Sinh[s]/2, z^2 - z Cosh[s]}, {s, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
    StreamScale -> None, StreamColorFunction -> Blue, ImageSize -> Large,
    FrameLabel -> {s, z}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

A more detailed image can be obtained using the approach illustrated in my answer to [238547](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238701/1063).

Comment: Excellent starting point. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Farhad  I have just added the full solution.  Best wishes

Comment: This is fantastic.Thank you for such a wonderful contribution. [@bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey)